# How to upload image from android to Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I was used XML-RPC to upload image, this worked for me, but so slow! 
The image size is 3.5M and it took 3 minutes to upload

```
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("res_model", res_model);
    map.put("res_name", res_name);
    map.put("type", "binary");
    map.put("res_field","image");
    map.put("res_id", res_id);
    map.put("name", "image");
    map.put("datas", image2Base64(imagePath));
    models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                db, uid, password,
                "ir.attachment", "create",
                asList(map)
        ));
```

And this is the image2Base64 method:

```
    private String image2Base64(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    String str = null;
    try {
        // Reading a Image file from file system
        FileInputStream imageInFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        imageInFile.read(imageData);

        imageInFile.close();
        str = Base64.encode(imageData);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Post the definition of `image2Base64` method.

Comment: @GeorgeD Tanks for your suggestion and i edited the question.